# Error If Else Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I've this simply script.
This is the first time i code a trading system and I'm not able to get rid of this siply script:

```
if ((CrossToPlotN > 40) and (CrossToPlotD < -40))
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
else if ((CrossToPlotN < -40) and (CrossToPlotD > 40))
    strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)
else if (crossunder(CrossToPlotN, CrossToPlotD))
    strategy.close("CloseBuy", strategy.long)
else (crossunder(CrossToPlotD, CrossToPlotD))
    strategy.close("CloseShort", strategy.short)
```

the error message is:
Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strategy.close()` does not have a parameter like `direction`.

This is its signature:

```
strategy.close(id, when, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message) → void

else if (crossunder(CrossToPlotN, CrossToPlotD))
    strategy.close("CloseBuy")
else (crossunder(CrossToPlotD, CrossToPlotD))
    strategy.close("CloseShort")
```

Secondly, your last statement is an `else`. You shouldn't pass any conditions to that expression.

```
var_declarationX = if condition  
      var_decl_then0  
      var_decl_then1  
      …  
      var_decl_thenN  
else if [optional block]  
      var_decl_else0  
      var_decl_else1  
      …  
      var_decl_elseN  
else  
      var_decl_else0  
      var_decl_else1  
      …  
      var_decl_elseN  
      return_expression_else
```

You either want:

```
else if (crossunder(CrossToPlotD, CrossToPlotD))
    strategy.close("CloseShort", strategy.short)
```

Or

```
else
    strategy.close("CloseShort", strategy.short)
```